# my screen resolution change will not save

Tags: 12.10, screen, display-resolution, mint

I have a desktop with 12.10 installed.
I have installed all the drivers and it works fine to edit the resolution om my screens.

The problem is, when I log in as a specific user, the resolution changes. I have tried to save the new screen resolution but it will not save.

I tried to save new configuration to `etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: Have you tried adding xorg.conf rules? Xorg is where you make persistent display changes.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by going to **Displays** and set it there also.
thats it! :)