# Resolutions settings not saved in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

In Ubuntu 20.04, I set the resolution to 1900 x 1200, but when I reboot, the resolution is set back to 2560 x 1600. How can I set the resolution to 1900 x 1200 so that it doesn't change?

Comment: How did you change the resolution?

Comment: I right clicked the desktop, and then clicked Display Settings. Then, a dropdown popped up asking for the resolution

Comment: I don't know how that menu works, but I asked to see if you used `xrandr`, which does not persist by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my screen resolution change will not save](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437919/my-screen-resolution-change-will-not-save)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the screen resolution using Ubuntu command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line)

Answer (score -1):

You can check [this link](https://www.ma-no.org/en/software/how-to-force-screen-s-resolution-in-ubuntu-and-make-it-permanent).

You should work with Terminal and set some command if your setting from GUI is temporary.

You could work with ***xrandr*** and your ***.xprofile*** in your system!